# Files Are Not Able To Process Although File Name is Saved In Metadata file

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using inbound-channel-adapter of spring integration for recursively picking the file from defined directory and process those file after being received from the channel.Although file name is being saved into metadata file but file is not being available to the channel for processing.

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="cfpFileIn"
    directory="${cfp.flight.data.dir}" auto-startup="true" scanner="csvDirScanner">
    <int:poller cron="${cfp.flight.data.dir.polling.delay}" ></int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Channel Initiator:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "cfpFileIn")
public void run(File file) {
    int jobCounter=1;
    String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
    logger.info("Running #################"+fileName );
........
}
```

csvScanner:

```
<bean id="csvDirScanner"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${cfp.flight.data.dir}" />
    <property name="filter" ref="csvCompositeFilter" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
</bean>
```

MetaData :

```
<bean name="metadataStore"
    class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore">
    <property name="baseDirectory" value="${metadata.dir}"></property>
</bean>
```

csvFilter:

```
<bean id="csvCompositeFilter"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg value="*.csv" />
            </bean>
            <ref bean="persistentFilter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

PersistentFilter:

```
<bean id="persistentFilter"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="metadataStore" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="flushOnUpdate" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Unclear what are you asking. You have to share some logs, stack traces. I see there is some custom `csvDirScanner`, but we don't know what it does. Maybe you can explain that part as well? Otherwise how do you expect a help from us if we have nothing to tackle. Also it isn't clear what is that `metadata file`.

Comment: metafile stores the files which the channels recieves..
I have given read write access to all the user for the directory but the serviceActivator do not process any file.
no logs are generated. Thats the issue.. but the file is being listed in metadata file.

Comment: OK. Now we have to see what is that `csvCompositeFilter`. You share so much custom names but without details, that I fully don't know how and who can help you...

Comment: csvCompositeFilter is just a filter which filters .csv file from the directory and provide it to the channel. thanks!

Comment: Great! Now, please, share DEBUG logs for `org.springframework.integration` category to see what's going on with your files

Comment: no logs are being generated. Only file name is getting saved into metadata,properties file